# SQL INSERT values if they do not already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want this query to insert all the distinct webshop dates in to the second table if they do not already exist for the webshop DataSets

The following query seems to ignore the `AND t1.[DataSet] = 'webshop'` parameter and not insert the new webshop values as they contain the same date ranges ie. they both contain `01/02/2013`

```
INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] ([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
select DISTINCT 'webshop', cast(T2.[OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) 
from webshop T2 
left join [ImportedDateRange] T1 
on cast(T2.[OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) = t1.[DateRange] 
where t1.[DateRange] is null
AND t1.[DataSet] = 'webshop'
```

The desired result is that it inputs the webshop date ranges only if they don't already exist for webshop (this prevents duplicate data if the query is run twice)

```
DataSet    DataRange
business   01/02/2013
business   02/02/2013
business   03/02/2013
webshop    01/02/2013
webshop    02/02/2013
webshop    03/02/2013
```

Comment: Use Group By clause , It will group the datasets

Comment: use a where not exists clause and select from your inserting table joining your table used for insert values making a join on corresponding keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move `t1.[DataSet] = 'webshop'` condition to the JOIN from the WHERE class

```
INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] ([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
select DISTINCT 'webshop', cast(T2.[OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) 
from webshop T2 
left join [ImportedDateRange] T1 
on cast(T2.[OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) = t1.[DateRange] 
         AND t1.[DataSet] = 'webshop'
where t1.[DateRange] is null
```